# Probability with poker hands?

Tags: probability

I really don't understand how to do these or the logic behind it. Could someone explain how to do them please? Here's the problems. In 5 card poker, find the probability of being dealt each of the following.

1. two pairs.
2. a hearts flush.

Comment: Do you know what $n \choose k$ is? What have you tried? I find it's easier to start these problems if you identify "sub-problems," for example: What is required to get one pair? You need a card value. Then you need the suits. The next pair? You still need a card value (it can't be the same as the first, presumably, because then it would be a four-of-a-kind). Then the suits.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS: There are $\binom{52}5$ possible $5$-card hands, all equally likely. If $n_{TP}$ is the number of hands that are two pairs, then the probability of getting one of these hands is $$\frac{n_{TP}}{\binom{52}5}\;.$$ Similarly, if $n_{HF}$ is the number of hands that are heart flushes, the probability of getting one of these hands is $$\frac{n_{HF}}{\binom{52}5}\;.$$ Your problem therefore boils down to finding $n_{TP}$ and $n_{HF}$.

A heart flush is simply any hand of $5$ hearts; calculating the number of these is similar to the calculation of the number of $5$-card hands, the only difference being that you’re choosing $5$ hearts instead of $5$ cards.

To build a hand that counts as two pairs, you can first choose $2$ ranks (like eight and king) for the pairs; in how many ways can that be done? For each of these two ranks you must choose $2$ of the $4$ cards of that rank; in how many ways can that be done? Finally, the fifth card must be of one of the $11$ other ranks; how many different choices are there for it? Once you answer those questions, you need to combine the answers to get the total number of such hands.